# Acceptance rate with sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a 'suggests' table with the following structure:

```
id(suggest_id) | author_id | accepted(true/false)
```

I want to order by the biggest acceptance rate, for example:

```
Jack had 10 suggests and he accepted 5 (50% acceptance rate)
John had 20 suggests and he accepted 5 (25% acceptance rate)
Steve had 10 suggests and he accepted 8 (80% acceptance rate)
```

This will return: Steve, Jack and John.

I think it's probably have to be with two SQL queries, one for number of suggests and the second for `accepted=true`.

Maybe it can be done with one query?

I'm using rails, so it can be done by rails as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you're representing accepted (true/false) something like...

```
select author_id, 
    sum(case when accepted ='true' then 1 else 0 end), 
    100.0*sum(case when accepted ='true' then 1 else 0  end)/count(*)
from yourtable
group by author_id
order by 100.0*sum(case when accepted ='true' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) desc
```

Comment: use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` to filter an aggregate. eg: `HAVING count(*)>10`

Comment: Thanks! btw, GROUP BY have to be before HAVING

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use plain ruby:

```
@authors_by_acceptance_rate = Array.new
@authors = Author.all
@authors.each do |author|
  @suggests = Suggest.find_by_author_id(author.id)
      accepted = 0
  @suggests.each do |suggest|
    if suggest.accepted
      accepted = accepted + 1
    end
  end
  acceptance_rate = accepted/@suggests.count
  @authors_by_acceptance_rate.push('name' => @author.name, 'accepted' =>     acceptance_rate)   
end
return @authors_by_acceptance_rate
```

I haven't tested this, so no guarantee it's working ...